# Postgres (table partition) + hasura

Tags: postgresql, graphql, partition, hasura

Appreciate for any suggestion and help.

I have so many problems with table partition + hasura.

1. Add schema.

Example:

I have table "message" (as a table parent) and "message_01", "message_02" (as a table child)

Go to Hasura console -> Data -> Schema.

- Only table child appear on hasura to add.

=> My problem: table parent "message" does not appear on hasura, i can not add.

=> My purpose: want to add table parent and query on table parent. How to do that ?

2. Set permission (insert,update,delete,select) on table parent:

=> My problem: Table "message" does not show up. Can not set permission.

=> My purpose: i want to set permission on only table parent (instead of set permission on so many table child)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't.  Hasura permissions are table based.  The relationship will only show if the role has access to the table. In that case you need to set the permission in each table.  You can use the allow list option to remove the mutation directly in the table.  Or you can set permission to only insert a record if exist a relationship.

Comment: Hi @LeonardoAlves,
How about the Question 1. 
Is there a way to add parent table in schema ?